# PostgreSQL pg_xlog and wal_keep_segments/max_wal_size

Tags: postgresql

We are running postgresql on centos7
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.18

in the conf file wal_keep_segments was commented out which should revert to the default setting of 0, also max_wal_size was set to 2GB.
The pg_xlog dir has 7000+ wal files and the size of the dir is 112GB.  Some of the wal files date back to 2017.

to test to see if the default for wal_keep_segments was not working correctly we set it to 200, yet the number of wal files continues to increase

I dont understand why these settings arent working, is there a way that these limits are overruled by other settings?

Comment: They are probably being kept to satisfy a replication slot, or because archiving is on but the archive command is failing.  figure out which is the case and fix it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Just to let you know, 9.6 is EOL - you should possibly consider upgrading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`max_wal_size`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/runtime-config-wal.html)

> Maximum size to let the WAL grow during automatic checkpoints. This is a soft limit; WAL size can exceed max_wal_size under special circumstances, like under heavy load, a failing archive_command, or a high wal_keep_segments setting.

This is the amount of WAL that triggers the creation of a checkpoint. Not related to `pg_xlog` maximum size.

`wal_keep_segments` is the amount of WAL to keep in excess of what is needed for crash recovery. This is the minimum size of the `pg_xlog` directory, not the maximum.

---

If postgresql does not remove old WAL segments, then they are needed for something. In addition to the needs of crash recovery and wal_keep_segments, these can be:

- active `archive_mode` without working (or even not defined) `archive_command`. Check these settings and `pg_stat_archiver` system view.
- inactive `replication slot`. Check [`pg_replication_slots`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/view-pg-replication-slots.html) system view.

Comment: Thank you we had a inactive replication slot